# Same cookie received twice, how to handle in the client?

Tags: python, http, cookies

I am trying to write a client to some web app. At one point it sends the following Set-cookie:

```
JSESSIONID=1BDC39CBF91C299C3330963D1EEFE399; Path=; HttpOnly; Secure, JSESSIONID=E6FFF3B159AFB9575D47662FC70DC161; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, XSESSIONID=b163abe6-bd6c-4381-9f68-01eeaee15a6c; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

It is unclear to me what is the meaning of having the same cookie name twice and what I am supposed to send back to the server?

I checked it with the following python code:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    from Cookie import SimpleCookie
else:
    from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

set_cookie = "JSESSIONID=1BDC39CBF91C299C3330963D1EEFE399; Path=; HttpOnly; Secure, JSESSIONID=E6FFF3B159AFB9575D47662FC70DC161; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, XSESSIONID=b163abe6-bd6c-4381-9f68-01eeaee15a6c; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly"

cookies = SimpleCookie()
cookies.load(set_cookie)

for name in cookies.keys():
    print("{} = {}".format(name, cookies[name].value))
    for field in ['secure', 'httponly', 'path']:
        print("   {}: {}".format(field, cookies[name][field]))
```

The python 2 code shows only one of the duplicate keys. The python 3 version does not recognize this at all.

```
$ /usr/bin/python cookie.py 
XSESSIONID = b163abe6-bd6c-4381-9f68-01eeaee15a6c
   secure: True
   httponly: True
   path: /
JSESSIONID = E6FFF3B159AFB9575D47662FC70DC161
   secure: True
   httponly: True
   path: /

$ python3 cookie.py
```

So I would like to understand what is the meaning of having the same key twice and what should be sent back to the server?
It would be also nice to understand why does the Python 3 library disregard the whole string. What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are really thinking they are the same? I mean, one is `XSESSIONID` which starts with `X`, while another is `JSESSIONID` which starts with `J`?

Comment: Besides the XSESSIONID, there are two versions of JSESSIONID in the cookie that I think differ in their Path, but I am not sure.